# Android Login Validation

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have tried everything and so frustrated at this stage with my android login, can someone help PLEASE! I have a login screen which asks user to enter email and password,when they click login it needs to go and check my `sqlite` db, if correct they will have successful login if not correct they will be asked to try again! I have posted my code below

**Login Activity**

```
   package com.example.finalproject;



import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class LoginActivity extends Activity{

    EditText EmailAdd;
    EditText Password;
    Button Login;
    Button NewUser;
    private SQLiteAdapter db;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);
        //addListenerOnButton();

        //Button mNewUser = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogMain);
        //mNewUser.setOnClickListener(this);

        EmailAdd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
        Password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

        Login = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogMain);
        Login.setOnClickListener(buttonLoginOnClickListener);
        NewUser = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNewUser);
        NewUser.setOnClickListener(buttonNewUserOnClickListener);

    }



    Button.OnClickListener buttonLoginOnClickListener
       = new Button.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //SQLiteAdapter db = new SQLiteAdapter (LoginActivity.this );
            SQLiteDatabase db = new SQLiteAdapter(LoginActivity.this).openToWrite();
            String email = EmailAdd.getText().toString();
             String password = Password.getText().toString();

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT email FROM MY_USERS_TABLE WHERE email= ? AND password=?", new String[] {email, password});
            if(c.moveToFirst()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent main = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
                startActivity(main);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed..\nTry Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            Intent register = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
            startActivity(register);
    }
    };
    /*@Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Working to here!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         String data1 = EmailAdd.getText().toString();
         String data2 = Password.getText().toString();

        boolean invalid = false;
        //uname == null || uname.length() == 0
        if(data1.equals("")){
            invalid = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email ID Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else if(data2.equals("")){
            invalid = true;
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email ID Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        if(invalid == false){
            //need to check here for valid email and password

            Intent i_register = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
            startActivity(i_register);
            EmailAdd.setText("");
            Password.setText("");
            finish();
        }
        /*switch(v.getId()){

        case R.id.btnLogMain:
            mEmailAdd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
            mPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);

            String uname = mEmailAdd.getText().toString();
            String pass = mPassword.getText().toString();

            if(uname.equals("") || uname == null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "email Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else if(pass.equals("") || pass == null){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Empty", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                boolean validLogin = validateLogin(uname, pass, LoginActivity.this);
                if(validLogin){
                    System.out.println("In Valid");
                    Intent i = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
                }
            }
            break;


        }*/
   // }
    //};

*RegisterActivity class*
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
//import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {

 EditText inputName, inputEmail, inputPassword;
 Button buttonRegister, buttonDeleteAll;
 TextView login;
 private SQLiteAdapter mySQLiteAdapter;
 ListView listContent;

 SimpleCursorAdapter cursorAdapter;
 Cursor cursor;


   /** Called when the activity is first created. */

@Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.register_activity);


       inputName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
       inputEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.email);
       inputPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);
       buttonRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.register);
       //buttonDeleteAll = (Button)findViewById(R.id.showAll);

       listContent = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.contentlist);

       mySQLiteAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
       mySQLiteAdapter.openToWrite();

       cursor = mySQLiteAdapter.queueAll();
      // String[] from = new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_ID, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_NAME, SQLiteAdapter.KEY_EMAIL,SQLiteAdapter.KEY_PASSWORD};
       /*int[] to = new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.text1, R.id.text2,R.id.text3};
       cursorAdapter =
        new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.row, cursor, from, to);
       listContent.setAdapter(cursorAdapter);*/

       buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(buttonAddOnClickListener);
       //buttonShowAll.setOnClickListener(buttonShowAllOnClickListener);
       //addListenerOnRegButton();

       TextView loginScreen = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.login);

       // Listening to login 
       loginScreen.setOnClickListener(TextLoginOnClickListener);
}

TextView.OnClickListener TextLoginOnClickListener
= new TextView.OnClickListener(){



@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);

}
};

   Button.OnClickListener buttonAddOnClickListener
   = new Button.OnClickListener(){



  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {



   String data1 = inputName.getText().toString();
   String data2 = inputEmail.getText().toString();
   String data3 = inputPassword.getText().toString();

   boolean invalid = false;

    if(data1.equals("")){
        invalid = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Name Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(data2.equals("")){
        invalid = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Email ID Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(data3.equals("")){
        invalid = true;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Missing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    if(invalid == false){
        mySQLiteAdapter.insert(data1, data2, data3);
        updateList();
           Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You are now registered",
                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Intent i_register = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(i_register);

        inputName.setText("");
        inputEmail.setText("");
        inputPassword.setText("");
        finish();
    }   




  }

   };




  /*Button.OnClickListener buttonShowAllOnClickListener1
   = new Button.OnClickListener(){

  @Override
  public void onClick(View arg0) {
      Intent i = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
  }

   };

 @Override
 protected void onDestroy() {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onDestroy();
  mySQLiteAdapter.close();
 }*/



 private void updateList(){
  //cursor.requery();
   }

}
    /* public boolean validateLogin(String uemail, String pass, Context context) {

        mydb = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mydb.openToWrite();
        //SELECT
        String[] columns = {"_id"};

        //WHERE clause
        String selection = "email=? AND password=?";

        //WHERE clause arguments
        String[] selectionArgs = {uemail,pass};

        Cursor cursor = null;
        try{
        //SELECT _id FROM login WHERE email=uemail AND password=pass
        cursor = db.query(SQLiteAdapter.MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null,null);

        //  startManagingCursor(cursor);

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        int numberOfRows = cursor.getCount();

        if(numberOfRows <= 0){

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed..\nTry Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return false;
        }


        return true;
    }*/



    Button.OnClickListener buttonNewUserOnClickListener
       = new Button.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
          public void onClick(View arg0) {

    }
    };



    }
```

**SQLiteAdapter **

```
package com.example.finalproject;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;

public class SQLiteAdapter {

 public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_PROJECT_DATABASE";
 public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_USERS_TABLE";
 public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
 public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
 public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
 public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
 public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

 //create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
 private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
  "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
  + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
  + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
  + KEY_EMAIL + " text not null, "
  + KEY_PASSWORD + " text not null);";

 private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
 private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

 private Context context;

 public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
  context = c;
 }

 public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
  sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
  sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
  return this; 
 }

 public SQLiteDatabase openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null,
                MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return sqLiteDatabase;
    }
 /*public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
  sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
  sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this; 
 }*/

 public void close(){
  sqLiteHelper.close();
 }

 public long insert(String name, String email, String password){

  ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
  contentValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
  contentValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
  contentValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
  return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
 }

 public int deleteAll(){
  return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
 }

 public Cursor queueAll(){
  String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL,KEY_PASSWORD};
  Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,
    null, null, null, null, null);

  return cursor;
 }

 public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

  public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
    CursorFactory factory, int version) {
   super(context, name, factory, version);
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
   db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
  }

  @Override
  public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }
 } 
}
```

I have tried many things but the when i hit login button a message appears "Unfortunately stopped working" thank u in advance for any help, it will be greatly appreciated

**LogCat**

```
The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    02-04 00:49:58.305: W/Trace(7726): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-04 00:49:58.305: W/Trace(7726): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-04 00:49:58.415: W/Trace(7726): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-04 00:49:58.415: W/Trace(7726): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-04 00:49:58.874: W/Trace(7726): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-04 00:49:58.884: W/Trace(7726): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-04 00:49:58.894: I/Choreographer(7726): Skipped 73 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    02-04 00:49:58.894: W/Trace(7726): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-04 00:49:58.894: W/Trace(7726): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-04 00:49:58.945: W/Trace(7726): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-04 00:49:58.975: W/Trace(7726): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-04 00:49:58.975: W/Trace(7726): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-04 00:49:59.024: W/Trace(7726): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
    02-04 00:49:59.104: D/AndroidRuntime(7726): Shutting down VM
    02-04 00:49:59.104: W/dalvikvm(7726): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
    02-04 00:49:59.154: E/AndroidRuntime(7726): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    02-04 00:49:59.154: E/AndroidRuntime(7726): java.lang.NullPointerException
    02-04 00:49:59.154: E/AndroidRuntime(7726):     at com.example.finalproject.LoginActivity$2.onClick(LoginActivity.java:165)
    02-04 00:49:59.154: E/AndroidRuntime(7726):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4202)
    02-04 00:49:59.154: E/AndroidRuntime(7726):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17340)
    02-04 00:49:59.154: E/AndroidRuntime(7726):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
    02-04 00:49:59.154: E/AndroidRuntime(7726):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    02-04 00:49:59.154: E/AndroidRuntime(7726):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    02-04 00:49:59.154: E/AndroidRuntime(7726):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
    02-04 00:49:59.154: E/AndroidRuntime(7726):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    02-04 00:49:59.154: E/AndroidRuntime(7726):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    02-04 00:49:59.154: E/AndroidRuntime(7726):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
    02-04 00:49:59.154: E/AndroidRuntime(7726):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
    02-04 00:49:59.154: E/AndroidRuntime(7726):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
    02-04 00:50:07.004: I/Process(7726): Sending signal. PID: 7726 SIG: 9
```

This code is still not working, Please someone help me!

Comment: change SQLiteDatabase db = null; to SQLiteAdapter db = new SQLiteAdapter (this) and check if it works

Comment: thanks for ur help but this doesn't work it has an error under the following code new SQLiteAdapter(this);

Comment: instead of "this" try using classname.this (classname is the name of your class)

Comment: No good either, still giving an error I also tried SQLiteDatabase db = new SQLiteAdapter (LoginActivity.this).openToRead();

Comment: what about SQLiteAdapter db = new SQLiteAdapter (classname.this )  ??

Comment: when i try SQLiteAdapter db = new SQLiteAdapter (classname.this ) I get an error in the following line of code: Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT email FROM MY_USERS_TABLE WHERE email= ? AND password=?", new String[] {email, password});

Comment: hey a small suggestion.. why dont you try something like writing a method in the SQLiteAdapter  class to retrieve required data too?
just a suggestion. If the one you are writing is compulsory we would try to help your way itself

Comment: Thank u I will try anything at this stage, been tryin all day to get this working! thanks for all ur help

Comment: firstly do you have data in your database? I doubt this because this might be the reason why you are getting null into your cursor object

Comment: you are using same edittext id to both usename and password. I think you should change this .. (Its not the reason for your error but it may irritate you later)

Comment: Yes I have lots of data in my db

Comment: Hey dear.. Do one thing...
Delete your database from the ddms view and run your code again..
your code is perfect.. Its working for me. (well i would suggest iTech solution.. Its simpler to uninstall the application rather than deleting it from the ddms view)

Comment: thank u so much for all ur help, i am trying it now and i will let u know if it works :)

Comment: hey, cleaned project, uninstalled it, even changed the name of my db as I created a new db but still not working,still showing "Unfortunately stopped working" wonder wud it be cause I have my db working in the main thread??

Comment: Oops this is really wierd

Comment: I know, I dont understand it at all, cud it be something to do with any of my other activities maybe?? ran out of ideas at this stage!!

Comment: Can you share the project you are working with..

Answer (score 1):

Your `db` is **NULL** and you use in the next line!

```
  SQLiteDatabase db = null;

  Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT email FROM MY_USERS_TABLE WHERE email='?' AND password='?'", new String[] {email, password});
```

Fix it by calling `SQLiteDatabase db = new SQLiteAdapter(LoginActivity.this).openToWrite();`

Comment: thank you for ur help but I tried this and am getting an error under the following code: new SQLiteAdapter(LoginActivity.this).openToRead();

Comment: Change the code as per my updated answer to use `openToWrite()` instead

Comment: tried that aswell and still stops working when I hit login button

Comment: What is the **exception**? without the StackTrace it is very difficult to help

Comment: I am sorry it just says "Unfortunately stopped working" in the emulator, I am new to java and android I apolgise

Comment: I assume you are using `eclipse`. right? Open the LogCat windows and copy the error from there.

Comment: Perfect, so what is the code in `LoginActivity.java line:165`?

Comment: Also, can you post your entire activity code including `onCreate` method

Comment: @iTech do you think null is because of absence of data in the database?

Comment: Line is SQLiteDatabase db = new SQLiteAdapter(LoginActivity.this).openToWrite(); I have updated to include all LoginActivity code

Comment: @G_S I do not think so because the code does not read the database values at all, just check if the cursor has valid data or no

Comment: yes i am suspecting that the cursor returns null to him. And his code works fine to me.. I am not having any data and am getting the failed try again toast

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code; I have tried it and it is working. I would suggest `clean` the project from eclipse, `uninstall` it completely from the emulator re-install and test again.

Comment: hey, cleaned project, uninstalled it, even changed the name of my db as I created a new db but still not working,still showing "Unfortunately stopped working"

Answer (score 1):

use this query

```
SELECT email FROM MY_USERS_TABLE WHERE email=? AND password=?
```

you are using '?' use ? only

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but you can try this.

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT email FROM MY_USERS_TABLE WHERE email= '?' AND password='?'", new String[] {email, password});
```

or

```
Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT email FROM MY_USERS_TABLE WHERE email= '+email+' AND password='+password+'";
```

Pardon me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have a few issues.

- You are setting the email to the password in the login activity as per `EmailAdd = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.password);`
- You are using `startActivity` to return from an activity when should be using `finish` to return to the invoking activity.

The following is an adaptation (less the registration) that pre-registers a user and password (Fred@email.com with password as the password).

**MainMenuActivity** :-

```
public class MainMenuActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    static boolean loggedin = false;
    SQLiteAdapter mAdapter;
    int requestcode = 100;
    Button menu;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);
        menu = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.mymenu);

        mAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(this);
        mAdapter.insert("Fred","Fred@email.com","password");
        if (!loggedin) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,LoginActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent,requestcode);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int reqcode, int reqresult, Intent intent) {
        if (reqcode == requestcode && reqresult == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            loggedin = true;
            menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            loggedin = false;
            Toast.makeText(this,"You are now Logged In",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**activty_main_menu** the layout used by the MainMenuActivity :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="so14881016login.so14881016login.MainMenuActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mymenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:text="Menu"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**LoginActivity** :-

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    EditText EmailAdd;
    EditText Password;
    Button Login;
    Button NewUser;
    private SQLiteAdapter db;
    int attempts = 3;


    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_activity);
        //addListenerOnButton();

        //Button mNewUser = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogMain);
        //mNewUser.setOnClickListener(this);

        EmailAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        Login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogMain);
        Login.setOnClickListener(buttonLoginOnClickListener);
        NewUser = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnNewUser);
        //NewUser.setOnClickListener(buttonNewUserOnClickListener); //<<<<IGNORED
    }

    Button.OnClickListener buttonLoginOnClickListener
            = new Button.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            //SQLiteAdapter db = new SQLiteAdapter (LoginActivity.this );
            SQLiteDatabase db = new SQLiteAdapter(LoginActivity.this).openToWrite();
            String email = EmailAdd.getText().toString();
            String password = Password.getText().toString();

            //Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT email FROM MY_USERS_TABLE WHERE email= ? AND password=?", new String[]{email, password});
            Cursor c = db.query(SQLiteAdapter.MYDATABASE_TABLE,
                    new String[]{SQLiteAdapter.KEY_EMAIL},
                    SQLiteAdapter.KEY_EMAIL + "=? AND " +SQLiteAdapter.KEY_PASSWORD + "=?",
                    new String[]{email,password},
                    null,null,null
            );
            if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // NO
                //Intent main = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainMenuActivity.class);
                //startActivity(main);
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK);
                finish(); //<<<< go back
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Failed..\nTry Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if (--attempts <= 0) {
                    setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED);
                    finish();
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

**login_activity** layout used by the above :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnLogMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Login"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNewUser"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add User"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**SQliteAdapter**

```
public class SQLiteAdapter {

    public static final String MYDATABASE_NAME = "MY_PROJECT_DATABASE";
    public static final String MYDATABASE_TABLE = "MY_USERS_TABLE";
    public static final int MYDATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public static final String KEY_ID = "_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    public static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "password";

    //create table MY_DATABASE (ID integer primary key, Content text not null);
    private static final String SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE =
            "create table " + MYDATABASE_TABLE + " ("
                    + KEY_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
                    + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
                    + KEY_EMAIL + " text not null, "
                    + KEY_PASSWORD + " text not null);";

    private SQLiteHelper sqLiteHelper;
    private SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase;

    private Context context;

    public SQLiteAdapter(Context c){
        context = c;
        openToWrite(); //<<<< Added
    }

    public SQLiteAdapter openToRead() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    public SQLiteDatabase openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
        sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null,
                MYDATABASE_VERSION);
        sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return sqLiteDatabase;
    }
 /*public SQLiteAdapter openToWrite() throws android.database.SQLException {
  sqLiteHelper = new SQLiteHelper(context, MYDATABASE_NAME, null, MYDATABASE_VERSION);
  sqLiteDatabase = sqLiteHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  return this;
 }*/

    public void close(){
        sqLiteHelper.close();
    }

    public long insert(String name, String email, String password){

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        contentValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
        contentValues.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
        return sqLiteDatabase.insert(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, contentValues);
    }

    public int deleteAll(){
        return sqLiteDatabase.delete(MYDATABASE_TABLE, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor queueAll(){
        String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL,KEY_PASSWORD};
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MYDATABASE_TABLE, columns,
                null, null, null, null, null);

        return cursor;
    }

    public class SQLiteHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public SQLiteHelper(Context context, String name,
                            SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
            super(context, name, factory, version);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            db.execSQL(SCRIPT_CREATE_DATABASE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    }
}
```

### Notes

- Some comments have been included.
- Note how result (OK or NOT OK) is returned to **MainMenuActivity** along with the use of `startActivityForResult`.
- The same concepts should be applied when invoking/returning to/from the **RegisterActivity**.

### Results

When first run skips immediately to the login activity :-

[image]

Invalid Login attempt stays at the above allowing retries (up to 3) if 3rd then returns to **MainMenuActivity** with Menu button invisible.

Valid login attempt returns to **MainMenuActivity** making button (your menu etc goes here) visible (does nothing) :-

[image]