# how to implement login for user having multiple role assigned in Android?

Tags: android-studio, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I have been researching on how to implement user roles in android applications but am not finding any examples. having 3 kinds of user student, teacher and admin I want after login based in their roles to get specific permission...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There a numerous way you could handle this. You would typically have a **column** in the table where the kind/type of the User, along with other User specific information would be stored.

- You could used a reference/mapping to a table that stores the type, which would cater for potential growth e.g. *say that the need for teacher assistants arose*.

After logging in you could :-

- return/pass a User object (class that is based upon the User) which would have the type within the object/class, from the Login dialog/activity/fragment.
- return/pass a unique identifier for the User, perhaps username/email and then query the database to extract the type, from the Login dialog/activity/fragment.
  -return multiple values via multiple Intent Extras from the login (similar to returning an class/Object but without the need to serialize (or equivalent)).
- Login from the initial activity, the Login retrieving the type/kind and also altering the layout making the Login specififc views invisible/gone and also revealing the logged in views. [This is part way of this option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881016/android-login-validation/49357158#49357158)

A search within Stack Overflow using **android sqlite login**

[image]

comes up with 630 hits

[image]

**It is highly likely that many of the question/answers could be useful.**